# Generating irreversible unique id based on fingerprint template

Tags: encryption

I'm a student who follows software engineering. I'm looking for method to generating irreversible unique id based on fingerprint for a software competition. What kind of encryption method can we use?

Please, Can anyone give some terms, topics or suitable references to study our selves to take our project to the success?

Comment: On the assumption that you will use the finger owning the print a second time for ID, you cannot just use cryptography.  Two hashes of the same finger will always be different.  Do you have an intermediate lossy algorithm to match the prints before the cryptographic operation?

Comment: @PaulUszak `Two hashes of the same finger will always be different.` - Erm, that's plain wrong. Maybe you should dive into fingerprint scanning and detection algos to understand why. Explaining it all in a comment would definitely be too broad… but your question about intermediate lossy algos underlines the fact you're missing basic information on the subject. I'm sure Security.SE will help you if you've got related questions.